# Use Windows 8 WinJS code for Window Phone 8

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, push-notification, winjs

Is there a way to re-use Windows 8 WinJS code for Window Phone 8 (for receiving push). Whether MPNS is supported from WinJS rather than C#.

Any Suggestions or Code Snippet is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean re-use?

Comment: re-use means using Windows8 WinJS code for Windows Phone 8 App that receives push with MPNS instead of WNS.